# Probability of the appearance of a disease

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The frequency of the Flu disease in the population is 1 in 10,000. A test that
checks if a person is infected with the disease is $99\%$ accurate on both sick and healthy
individuals. One takes the test and gets a positive response (test says he is infected). What
is the probability that he is actually infected?
My reasoning was as follows:
C: correct test
I: incorrect test
D: desease
HD: have desease

$P(C) = 0,99$
$P(I) = 0,01$
$P(D) = 0,0001$
$P(I) \to \ ?$

$P(HD) = P(C)P(D|C) + P(I)P(D|I)$
$P(HD) = P(C)P(D) + P(I)P(D)$  Are independents
$P(HD) = P(D)[P(C)+P(I)]$
$P(HD) = P(D)$

Is correct my reasoning? Why if not.

Comment: If your reasoning were correct, there would be no point in ever testing for a disease, as your chance of having it would not change whether the result was positive or negative.. (BTW, "desease" means "to die" - it is a different word from "disease"). Instead consider this: if $1$ million people are in the population and were tested, and the indicated ratios are all perfectly correct, how many people would be sick? how many sick people test positive? test negative? how many non-sick people test positive? test negative?

Comment: Could you guide me with the answer formula and on the basis of that explain me?

Comment: No. I will not give you a formula that you can rotely plug things into and get an answer out of that you do not understand in the slightest, (which your reliance on in the past is exactly why you've produced this wrong result). Instead I will tell you again to figure out the four values I described for a population of $1$ million tested people, then use them to figure what ratio of the people with a positive test are actually sick.

Comment: 1/100000 are sick, in a million it would be 10/1000000

Comment: $1$ in $10,000$ are sick, not $1$ in $100,000$.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, it would be 100/1000000. The proportion remains

Comment: So there are 100 sick people. How many non sick? How many sick tested positive, how many sick tested negative? How many non-sick tested positive? how many non-sick tested negative?

Comment: I'm getting to the point, now I would have P(ND | C), P (ND | I), P (D | C), P (D | I). But to be sick, just enough with P (D | C), P (D | I), what am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is actually answering my questions! How many of the 100 sick people will test positive? How many non-sick people are there? How many of the non-sick people will test positive?

Comment: 100 sick in 1 million, 999 900 not sick in 1 million, 990000 successful tests, 10,000 incorrect tests.  Can I now use 99% on those 100 patients? I'm well stuck man

Comment: You can use your accuracy (99%) both on sick and on healthy counts.

Comment: Man I did: 100 * 99% = 99 (TP), 999900*99%=989901(TN), 99900 - 989901 = 9999(FP) and 100 - 99 = 1(FN). Then P = TP/(TP + TN), but if I do that then I get 0,0001, the initial probability T-T. What is wrong now?!?!?!?

Comment: The true negatives don't have positive as outcome. You should add true and false positives at the denominator of your expression.

Comment: You are close now. But you have not correctly identified the population for the result. We are looking for the probability that *if someone has a positive result*, they are actually sick. So we are only concerned with people who have tested positive. Of them, 99 are sick, and the remaining 9999 are well. You need $\frac{\text{TP}}{\text{TP + FP}}$

Comment: Thanks guys, I understood and I already turned in the homework!!!